# Compatibility Administrator tool (MS-ACT): how to add parameters to launching program?

Tags: windows, compatibility, application-launch

Does anyone know how to force a parameter to be added to a program at startup using Compatibility Administrator (from MS-ACT: Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit)?

The "RedirectEXE" Compatibility Fix seems a good candidate, since it can pass also a parameter but was originally designed to redirect an exe1 launch to another exe2 (for old software launchers/installers running the "wrong" exe at launch)...
I tried as Parameter

```
.\old_program.exe -myparameter
```

but the task execution enters a loop because it kills the old_program.exe execution and relaunch it forever (since the fix was designed to actually start ANOTHER exe).

Ideas apart copying the same exe1 as exe2 (or using makelink...) to workaround the loop?

P.S.
Of course using a Shortcut is out of question...